# List of bullets c++

Tags: c++, directx-9

I'm writing the Contra Game by Directx9 and c++
please help me about list of bullets

i'm trying below code but it's error: vector intertor incompatible

```
 std::vector<Bullet*> bullets
if (mKeyboard->IsKeyPress(DIK_X))
{
    Bullet* toShoot = new Bullet(noneType, _position.x, _position.y, RIGHT);
    toShoot->Init();
    bullets.push_back(toShoot);
}
```

Update Funtion:

```
 std::vector<Bullet*>::iterator it = bullets.begin();


 while ((it) != bullets.end())
  {
    (*it)->Update(gameTime, c);

    if ((*it)->IsLive() == false)
    {
        bullets.erase(it++);
    }
  }
```

Render funtion

```
std::vector<Bullet*>::iterator it = bullets.begin();
while (it != bullets.end())
{
    if ((*it)->IsLive())
    {
        (*it++)->Render(gr, cx, cy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does your code run? What error do you get? What does the code do when it runs? What do you want it to do? You have to make sure to address all of these questions for us to be able to help you...otherwise, we don't really know what you're even asking.

Comment: The problem was stated reasonably clearly (excusing the typos) and the diagnosis would be far from obvious to a C++ nube.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just increment an iterator passed to `erase(…)`. Do this instead:

```
if (!(*it)->IsLive()) {
  it = bullets.erase(it);
} else {
  ++it;
}
```

Your Render function has a different bug. It gets stuck on the first non-live bullet, since the increment is inside the if-block. This is one reason `for(…)` is usually preferable to `while(…)`:

```
for (auto it = bullets.begin(); it != bullets.end(); ++it) {
    if (…) {
        …
    }
}
```

In fact, the Update function should be likewise changed, but omit the `++it`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Update` function, you are calling the `erase` while iterating over a vector.  The problem is that your `it` iterator can get invalidated if it is being used in the loop at the same time you're erasing from the vector.

The alternative is to use the `erase/remove_if` idiom:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
bullets.erase(std::remove_if(bullets.begin(), bullets.end(), 
              [&](Bullet& b) { b.Update(gameTime, c); return !b.IsLive(); }),
              bullets.end());
```

The algorithm function `remove_if()` is called to determine which bullets will be removed by the `erase()` function.  Note that the lambda includes the logic you used to determine if a bullet should be removed.